# Handling facebook exceptions

Tags: php, facebook, exception, facebook-php-sdk

maybe it is simple, but i do not know how to do it, so i ask.
Sometimes i get an exception from facebook e.g. posting an action has failed. Normally it works but sometimes dont. I use the php sdk and when there is sth. wrong i get an facebook exception and the whole site stops running.

Is there a way i can ignore these exceptions and store it in database instead, so that the rest of the website works?

I think it is in the base_facebook.php, hopefully someone knows what line i must change.

Thank you very much

Ruven

Comment: `try { /* code that throws an exception */ } catch (Exception $e) { /* handle error, which can include "do nothing" if you like */ }`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to touch the Facebook SDK. You can catch the exceptions and do whatever you like with them (such as storing them in a database).

Example:

```
try {
    // Facebook code here
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Display the exception (or whatever else you like)
    echo $e->getType()." ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: lol thats it? And i am searching through the sdk, wtf. But it seems so, that this is doing the trick. Thank you man.